# Create a new slide layout and copy contents from other powerpoint slide layout

Tags: apache-poi, openxml, xslf

This is my use-case:

I have two power-point files. I want to copy all of the slide templates from one powerpoint to other. I could not find any API like createTemplate() in MasterSlide, so in order to do it, I create a new XSLFSlideLayout using one of the template's (which exist in the same powerpoint) PackagePart and then using importContent() to it, to copy the template from other powerpoint. Here is a short version of it :

```
XMLSlideShow xmlSlideShow1 = new XMLSlideShow(templateInputStream1);
XMLSlideShow XmlSlideShow2 = new XMLSlideShow(templateInputStream2);
XSLFSlideLayout newLayout = null;

try {
  newLayout = new XSLFSlideLayout(xmlSlideShow1.getSlideMasters().get(0).getSlideLayouts().get(0).getPackagePart());
} catch (IOException | XmlException e){
  LOGGER.error("Unable to create new layout", e);
}
// breaks here
newLayout.importContent(xmlSlideShow2.getSlideMasters().get(0).getSlideLayouts().get(0));
return userXmlSlideShow.createSlide(newLayout);
```

And it breaks when importContent is called:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: SlideMaster was not found for Name:
>   /ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout1.xml - Content Type:
>   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideLayout+xml
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlideLayout.getSlideMaster(XSLFSlideLayout.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlideLayout.getMasterSheet(XSLFSlideLayout.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlideLayout.getMasterSheet(XSLFSlideLayout.java:36)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFShape.fetchShapeProperty(XSLFShape.java:307)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSimpleShape.getXfrm(XSLFSimpleShape.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSimpleShape.setAnchor(XSLFSimpleShape.java:169)
>     at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFShape.copy(XSLFShape.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSimpleShape.copy(XSLFSimpleShape.java:711)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextShape.copy(XSLFTextShape.java:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet.importContent(XSLFSheet.java:372)

I'm using poi-3.15. Any leads would be of great help.